# How to bypass CORS in ajax call by any extension/add-ons

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, wcf, cors

I have a `WCF service` which is showing `cross origin` problem. I want to test that service by bypassing the CORS issue, I have added an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) in `chrome`. but still issue exist. Is there any extension / add-ons / plugin to just test the service at my end by bypassing the cors issue.

**Edit**

after google chrome suggestion

```
framework7.js:14806 GET http://serviceslink?order=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&order=%5Bobject%20Object%5D 400 (Bad Request)a.ajax @ framework7.js:14806a.(anonymous function) @ framework7.js:14806(anonymous function) @ main.js:725i.triggerPageCallbacks @ framework7.js:14806i.pageInitCallback @ framework7.js:14806i.router._load @ framework7.js:14806(anonymous function) @ framework7.js:14806preprocess @ framework7.js:14806t @ framework7.js:14806(anonymous function) @ framework7.js:14806complete @ framework7.js:14806r @ framework7.js:14806g.onload @ framework7.js:14806
jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5 GET http://servicelink/?ord…%5B1%5D%5BItem_Id%5D=2&order%5B1%5D%5BQty%5D=1&order%5B1%5D%5Bprice%5D=6.5 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: you can add response headers 'allow-origin: *' to allow all the incoming requests in your WCF service.

Comment: if haven't access to web service?

Comment: We need more code to help you with this, however technically it seems that it's another question and this one is solved :)

Comment: what more is required ?

Comment: It's probably server-side issue, that you're getting `Bad-request` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run Chrome with `--disable-web-security` flag. But be advised advised about this [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=575690)

On Mac it'll be

`open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir`

Comment: added above in question